# Redirect all URLs (Known and Unknown) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a neat solution to achieve this goal in Rails in one place?(Preferably `routes.rb`). Right now for redirecting I've made a before filter like this:

```ruby
...
unless [temp_url].include? request.url
  redirect_to temp_path
end
```

This approach works for the known routes. Unknown routes will get 404 error. For unknown it's possible to use this in `routes.rb`:

```ruby
match "/*other" => redirect("/temp/index")
```

Apparently we don't have access to `request` object in `routes.rb`. Is there a better solution to cover both known and unknown redirection in `routes.rb`?

Comment: I’d say having these two separate functionalities is just enough. Cases where a ”catch-all” is needed are really rare, so having one line of extra for them should be feasible.

Answer (score 2):

**Unknown Routes Redirection to root**

`routes.rb`

```
match '*path' => redirect('/')
```

Using the above you can redirect all unknown routes to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at `before_filter`:

For example, the following code always calls the find_post method in show, edit, update and destroy endpoints. The same logic can be used for your case.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_post, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def update
    @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
  end

  protected    
    def find_post
      @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```